# Adjust cropper instead of image zoom react native image crop picker

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to adjust the cropper instead of zoom in and zoom out of image.

I am using `react-native-image-crop-picker`. I want the cropper to move rather than the image clicked.

Here is my code:

```
imageCropView(){
    ImagePicker.openCropper({
      hideBottomControls:true,
      path: this.state.path,
      width: 300,
      height: 400
    }).then(image => {
      console.log(image);
      this.setState({
        path:image.path
      },()=>{
        let arr = this.state.imagesArr;
        arr.push(this.state.path);
        this.setState({
          imagesArr:arr,path:null
        })
      })
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

done by using the property:

> `freeStyleCropEnabled` to true